# One to Many Relationship Laravel getting error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have relationship between Video Category and Video Courses, one Category can Have many courses, I want to get video courses through video category item but getting error

Video Category Model

```
class VideoCategory extends Model
{
    public function video_courses(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\VideoCourse');
    }   
}
```

Video Course Model

```
class VideoCourse extends Model
{

    public function video_category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(VideoCategory::class);
    }

}
```

My View

```
@forelse ($category->video_courses as $video_course)
   <a href="#"">{{$course->title}}</a>
@empty
   <p>No Video Courses Available</p>
@endforelse
```

Error:
(4/4) ErrorException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'video_courses.video_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `video_courses` where `video_courses`.`video_category_id` = 2 and `video_courses`.`video_category_id` is not null and `video_courses`.`deleted_at` is null) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\QuickLMS\resources\views\category.blade.php)

Comment: Try it `$courses = VideoCategory::find(1)->video_courses`. And make sure it returns collection. Then look for the following answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second parameter of each belongsTo and hasMany you must define the foreign key that relates this two tables:

```
class VideoCourse extends Model
{

    public function video_category()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(VideoCategory::class, 'video_category_id');
    }

}


class VideoCategory extends Model
{
    public function video_courses(){
        return $this->hasMany(VideoCourse::class,'video_category_id');
    }   
}
```

The error says you don't have the video_category_id field as foreign key in your table. Pass your foreign key column name in the second parameter.

Comment: @Nurdaulet Shamilov what's your foreign key in the videoCourses table?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your table columns don't match your many to one relation. Your video_courses table should have a video_category_id column. That way, each course record references which category it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a different key for the `id` make sure you provide that in the relationship method, for example:

```
public function video_courses() {
    // second parameter is the foreign key.
    return $this->hasMany(VideoCourse::class, 'video_course_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the key for the relationship in the `VideoCategory` Model

```
public function video_courses() {
return $this->hasMany(VideoCourse::class, 'video_course_id');
}
```